# powermock error java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "android.support.v4.app

Tags: android, powermock, powermockito

I am using powermock to test and Android activity

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21)
@PowerMockIgnore({ "org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*"})
@PrepareForTest(EpicDetailFragment.class)
public class ITestActivityTest {

    private ITestDemoActivity activity;

    private FragmentManager fm;

    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    @Before
    public void initSetup(){
        activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(IGDemoActivity.class).create().get();
        fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        assertTrue(activity != null);
    }

 
}
```

Anyway I get the following linkageError

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction.add(ILandroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction;" the class loader (instance of org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader) of the current class, com/pips/ftse/igdemo/activities/IGDemoActivity, and the class loader (instance of org/robolectric/internal/bytecode/InstrumentingClassLoader) for the method's defining class, android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction, have different Class objects for the type android/support/v4/app/Fragment used in the signature
```

Any idea what this is all about and how to solve it ?

I thought perhaps the ignore `android.*` would work but it does not.

Answer (score 2):

This error means, that a class and his parent is loaded by different class loaders.When a method from super class is called from child class instance then a method cannot be linked(used) because different class object instance.

You have the error, because the "android.*" is added to `@PowerMockIgnore`, but you are trying prepare for test the class `EpicDetailFragment` which obviously extends `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction`.

What to do? Try to remove "android.*" from ignore and try to use more specific paths to ignore some part of Android which cannot be re-loaded via PowerMock. 
Also I'd recommend try to use `@PowerMockRunnerDelegate` instead using rules.